# Create database with migration beego

Tags: go, beego

I already created migration file via `bee generate migration create_users_table`. Then i had one file in folder database/migrations/20171205_154034_create_users_table.go
This is my file :

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/astaxie/beego/migration"
)

// DO NOT MODIFY
type CreateUsersTable_20171205_154034 struct {
    migration.Migration
}

// DO NOT MODIFY
func init() {
    m := &CreateUsersTable_20171205_154034{}
    m.Created = "20171205_154034"

    migration.Register("CreateUsersTable_20171205_154034", m)
}

// Run the migrations
func (m *CreateUsersTable_20171205_154034) Up() {
    m.CreateTable("users","InnoDB","utf8")
    m.PriCol("id").SetAuto(true).SetNullable(false).SetDataType("INT(10)").SetUnsigned(true)
}

// Reverse the migrations
func (m *CreateUsersTable_20171205_154034) Down() {
    m.SQL("DROP TABLE users")
}
```

Finally, i run `bee migrate -conn="username:password@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/mydb"`.
I got `Migration successful!` no error. But i did not have users table in database. Whats wrong?
Thank you for reading. Hope anyone help me

Answer (score 0):

To address your problem, you're not executing your SQL in the end.

Add the following line to your `Up()`:

```
m.SQL(m.GetSQL())
```